# Restrict gensim similarity calculations to a subset of a corpus

Tags: python, gensim

I am looking to calculate the similarity between documents using gensim on Python.

I want a way to be able to restrict the calculations to only a subset of the corpus. Specifically, my documents have an associated year, and i want a way of only computing similarities between the search document and other document which have the same value for that variable.

I can not see any instructions on e.g. http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/simserver.html on how to associate additional variables with each document, and in turn how to restrict the similarities to only those documents - and indeed what i am trying to do may not be feasible. My question is thus, is this it is possible, or is the only way to achieve this to  use multiple corpuses.

Answer (score 0):

You could work around it just by ignoring results that are not for your target year.

1. Create a document2year_dict (document, year) for your documents.
2. Get the list of documents in distance order from
   target_document.
3. Iterate through the list and discard documents
   if document2year_dict[current_document] != target_year